# Password authentication failed for user

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am having a problem trying to run psql on my MacOs. The psql command returns the following error:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "luicruz"
```

How could I fix this?

I try to put my `sudo` password when the terminal request me the password, but it didn't work. The only password that works is for the default user "postgres" that I set the password when I install the app on my system.

I don't know why the user 'luicruz' was automatically created, I didn't create this user or set a password for this user.

And now I can't use the psql command.

Below is an image showing the login/Group roules of the Pg Admin 4 and also the return of the commands in the terminal

[image]

Comment: Why do you think there's a `luicruz` role? Your screenshot is showing there isn't. Are you asking how to create one?

Comment: The problem is that the `psql` command needs to be used in addition to the database name, and I didn't know that. After creating the database, I was able to use the command apart from the psql code. 

Like : psql database_name 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `psql` command needs to be used in addition to the database name, and I didn't know that. After creating the database, I was able to use the command apart from the `psql` command.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).